# convert Access to mysql commands

Tags: mysql

One of our customer has an Access database in his own server and I need to import it to a linux server with mysql in my own server.
In other words, I need to convert Access to mysql commands (inserts basically).

I've tried the DBWScript which works fine although it does not allow to export only one table. It exports all tables. What I'm doing now is exporting all the tables to a sql file and then I filter it taking only the inserts I really need.

I'd like to know if anybody knows a software like DBWScript that can be run in console-mode and permits to export only one table from a database, because that table has a lot of rows (up to 100.000) and it has no sense to export all the other tables if I am not going to use them. That increases the conversion time a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809654/how-to-import-a-mdbaccess-database-to-mysql

Answer (score 1):

I finally used a software called "Bullzip MS Access to MySQL" and it works like a charm!
This is the author's website: http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

It allows yo to select the desired table and desired columns in different tables, apart from creating a batch script to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool in [dbForge Studio for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/).

Open Data Import wizard, select MS Access format, specify other options and save template file. Then use this template file (*.dit) in command line mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using tips to [converting MS Access to MySQL](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/ms-access-to-mysql-with-relationships/)